# TypeScript error "Could not find a declaration file for module" - unable to fix

Tags: javascript, typescript, element-ui

I'm normally able to resolve this error easily enough, but this time nothing seems to work.

My `main.ts` file has this:

```
import locale from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/en';
```

The error:

```
ERROR in /Volumes/SuperData/Sites/reelcrafter/rc-ts/src/main.ts
6:20 Could not find a declaration file for module 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/en'. '/Volumes/SuperData/Sites/reelcrafter/rc-ts/node_modules/element-ui/lib/locale/lang/en.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/element-ui` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'element-ui';`
    4 | import store from './store';
    5 | import ElementUI from 'element-ui';
  > 6 | import locale from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/en';
      |                    ^
    7 | import VueDragDrop from 'vue-drag-drop';
    8 | import './styles/element-setup.scss';
    9 | import './bootstrap/amplify-setup';
No lint errors found
Version: typescript 3.0.1, tslint 5.11.0
```

In my `declarations.d.ts` at root level, I added the following:

```
declare module 'element-ui';
```

This doesn't fix it. Nor does `declare module 'element-ui/*';`. How do I fix it?

Reproduction repo: https://github.com/ffxsam/repro-element-ts-bug

Comment: Have you checked your tsconfig.json file?

Comment: `declare module 'element-ui/*';` is working for me.  Are you using a build tool other than plain `tsc`?

Comment: @Abhishek Checked it for what? Could you be more specific?

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I'm in a Vue project scaffolded by vue-cli 3.0.

Comment: I don't see vue-cli 3.0 on https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli .  I was just going to try creating a new project to see if I can reproduce the problem.  Maybe it will be easier if you do that, and if you get the problem, publish the repository so I can look.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen Not sure what you mean by "I don't see vue-cli 3.0". Just do `npm i -g @vue/cli` and you'll have vue-cli 3.0. Then `vue create myapp`.

Comment: Oh, they moved to a scoped NPM package, which I probably could have found in a web search... Anyway, given that I've already spent a fair amount of time answering Stack Overflow questions from you, I'd ask you to create the reproduction project and publish it for me rather than vice versa (or you can wait and see if someone else offers help).

Comment: BTW, https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26392 is for the error message erroneously telling you to `declare module 'element-ui'`.

Comment: Man, that checker.ts file is ugly. Why are they using such huge property names on `Diagnostics`?! Anyway, I'll put together a repro in a bit here. Also, I think their advice on installing types is wrong. It should be `npm install -D @types/blah`. Those typedefs are not needed in production, obviously.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen Ugh, I can't reproduce it in a fresh repo. It's literally the same code as in my project. I'm not sure why my project is not behaving properly.

Comment: I guess you get to bisect the content until you find what is causing the difference.  Good catch re `npm install -D`; I updated the pull request.

Comment: Got it! Updated my post to include the repo link. It's the `import Vue from 'vue'` line in `declarations.d.ts` that mucks things up for whatever reason.

Comment: Moving `declare module 'element-ui/*'` to its own `.d.ts` file fixes it.

Answer (score 5):

Create a declaration file called `shims-element-ui.d.ts` with following contents:

```html
declare module 'element-ui/*';
```